# Interrupting button action if fields are not populated in Opportunity Object

Tags: javascript, custom-button

I have the following code to prevent sales from sending documents via DocuSign if a field or two are not populated in the opportunity object. Its not working. I'm getting an error.

The code:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_JavaScript")}
DocuSign_CreateEnvelope()

if(ISPICKVAL(ISBLANK( Documents_Path__c ), ISBLANK( Document_Date__c )) {
alert ("Please Review the Opportunity flags before proceeding");
};
```

Error:

```
na7.salesforce says:
A problem with the OnClick JavaScript for this button or link was encountered:

Unexpected Token {
```

I tried fixing the "{" but didn't seem to work. I'm a bit confused here. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use merge fields, and proper object/field names:

```
if({!OR(ISPICKVAL(Opportunity.Documents_Path__c,''), ISBLANK(Opportunity.Document_Date__c))}) {
```

Comment: It caused to get an additional error "Error: Incorrect number of parameters for function 'ISPICKVAL()'. Expected 2, received 1"

Comment: fixed... but still getting the following error:
"Unexpected end of input"

Comment: its working now and the error is showing. but the envelope is still being created. I'll add question for that issue.

Answer (score 1):

As is, your if statement is missing a closing parenthesis `)`.

```
// numbers represent the number of open parenthesis (should be 0 at the end)
if(ISPICKVAL(ISBLANK( Documents_Path__c ), ISBLANK( Document_Date__c )) {
  1          2      3                   2          3                 21
```

That said, your javascript has other issues:

- `ISPICKVAL` and `ISBLANK` are not javascript functions (you'd need to use merge expression syntax, e.g. `{!ISPICKVAL(ISBLANK(...))...}`
- `ISPICKVAL` is not required here (and if it were, you're not using it correctly)
- Are you sure you want to create the DocuSign envelope before running your validity check?

Comment: No. I'm trying to stop the button from working if a field in the opportunity is empty.

Comment: @HUBBY0716 my last point (about creating the envelope before doing your check) is that your current approach doesn't stop the envelope from being created (which you say is an issue in the comments on sfdcfox's answer). You're currently creating the envelope, and then checking to see if you should have created it. Preventing the 'action' (creating the envelope) of your button means you need to do your check before you attempt to create the envelope (and only create the envelope if your checks pass).

Answer (score -1):

I think you are missing closing ")" tag for if statement.
Please try  the following code

{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_JavaScript")}
DocuSign_CreateEnvelope();

if(ISPICKVAL(ISBLANK( Documents_Path__c ), ISBLANK( Document_Date__c ))) {
alert ("Please Review the Opportunity flags before proceeding");
};

Comment: its now giving me an error that ISPICKVAL is not defined...

Comment: fixed this error